# All colors gone after adding custom color in tailwind

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I just added a custom color to tailwind like this:

```
colors: {
         'slate': '#475569'
      },
```

Then I ran `npm run watch` and the color worked as expected, but all other colors are gone, they are wiped from the project and I can t use them because they don t show up in auto completion, nor do they work when typing them out myself.

Edit: When I delete the custom color and rerun `npm run watch` the old colors work again, but I need to add a custom one :/

Comment: Did you try to run ```npm run dev```? this will compile things and probably will solve your issue.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

i suspect you replace the default colors with the colors you add. in order to extend the default colors the tailwind.config.js file should look like this

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        brown: {
          50: '#fdf8f6',
        },
      }
    },
  },
}
```

if you place the **colors** key out of the **extend** key then the default colors will be removed.

Comment: in my case, the issue still occured

Comment: @Forbidden How did you solve this? Same for me

Comment: The issue was cause because I was using the same name that tailwind is already defined, example: red, red is already build-in color of tailwind, so when I extend red with: red is only equals to '#00ff' and not object type, those reds colors that are already defined will be replaced and red-800 or other will not be accessable